# How to specify Task("A").IsDependantOn("B") with specific arguments

Tags: c#, dependencies, arguments, task, cakebuild

Im using Cakebuild to define a standard task dependency:

```
var env = Argument("env", "DEV");

//… many tasks 

Task("Run-Integration-Tests")
        .IsDependentOn("Build")
        .Does(() =>
    {
        NUnit("./src/**/bin/release/*.Tests.dll");
    });
```

I'd like "Run-Integration-Tests" to depend on "Build" specifically with "env" argument of "UAT" (so it is set to "UAT" if not passed). Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add criteria to the task:

```
var env = Argument("env", "DEV");

Task("Run-Integration-Tests")
    .WithCriteria(env == "UAT")
    .IsDependentOn("Build")
    .Does(() => { ... })
```

would run the `Run-Integration-Tests` Tasks only if `env` is set to "UAT".

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to manipulate the directed acyclic graph (DAG) that Cake uses prior to executing the script.  This can be done by defining the task as a variable, and then calling the methods on the task as required.  For example:

```
var IntegrationTask = Task("Run-Integration-Tests")
    .Does(() =>
{
    NUnit("./src/**/bin/release/*.Tests.dll");
});
```

Then, at some point else in your script do:

```
if(env == "UAT")
{
    IntegrationTask.IsDependentOn("Build");
}
```

This technique is used extensively in [Cake.Recipe](https://github.com/cake-contrib/Cake.Recipe) to manipulate the DAG depending on what type of project is being built.  An example of this can be seen here:

https://github.com/cake-contrib/Cake.Recipe/blob/develop/Cake.Recipe/Content/build.cake#L549-L590

Namely:

```
private static void SetupTasks(bool isDotNetCoreBuild)
{
    var prefix = isDotNetCoreBuild ? "DotNetCore-" : "";
    BuildParameters.Tasks.CreateNuGetPackagesTask.IsDependentOn(prefix + "Build");
    BuildParameters.Tasks.CreateChocolateyPackagesTask.IsDependentOn(prefix + "Build");
    BuildParameters.Tasks.TestTask.IsDependentOn(prefix + "Build");
    BuildParameters.Tasks.DupFinderTask.IsDependentOn(prefix + "Build");
    BuildParameters.Tasks.InspectCodeTask.IsDependentOn(prefix + "Build");
    BuildParameters.Tasks.PackageTask.IsDependentOn("Analyze");
    BuildParameters.Tasks.PackageTask.IsDependentOn("Test");
    BuildParameters.Tasks.PackageTask.IsDependentOn("Create-NuGet-Packages");
    BuildParameters.Tasks.PackageTask.IsDependentOn("Create-Chocolatey-Packages");
    BuildParameters.Tasks.UploadCodecovReportTask.IsDependentOn("Test");
    BuildParameters.Tasks.UploadCoverallsReportTask.IsDependentOn("Test");
    BuildParameters.Tasks.AppVeyorTask.IsDependentOn("Upload-Coverage-Report");
    BuildParameters.Tasks.AppVeyorTask.IsDependentOn("Publish-Chocolatey-Packages");
    BuildParameters.Tasks.InstallReportGeneratorTask.IsDependentOn(prefix + "Build");

    if (!isDotNetCoreBuild)
    {
        if (BuildParameters.TransifexEnabled)
        {
            BuildParameters.Tasks.BuildTask.IsDependentOn("Transifex-Pull-Translations");
        }
        BuildParameters.Tasks.TestTask.IsDependentOn("Test-NUnit");
        BuildParameters.Tasks.TestTask.IsDependentOn("Test-xUnit");
        BuildParameters.Tasks.TestTask.IsDependentOn("Test-MSTest");
        BuildParameters.Tasks.TestTask.IsDependentOn("Test-VSTest");
        BuildParameters.Tasks.TestTask.IsDependentOn("Test-Fixie");
        BuildParameters.Tasks.InstallOpenCoverTask.IsDependentOn("Install-ReportUnit");
    }
    else
    {
        if (BuildParameters.TransifexEnabled)
        {
            BuildParameters.Tasks.DotNetCoreBuildTask.IsDependentOn("Transifex-Pull-Translations");
        }
        BuildParameters.Tasks.TestTask.IsDependentOn(prefix + "Test");
        BuildParameters.Tasks.InstallOpenCoverTask.IsDependentOn("Install-ReportGenerator");
        BuildParameters.Tasks.PackageTask.IsDependentOn(prefix + "Pack");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a method to substitute variable conditionally.

```
void ArgumentIfTask<T>(string taskName, ref T argument, string argumentName, T argumentValue)
{
    if(Argument("target", "Default") != taskName)
    {
        return;
    }

    argument = Argument(argumentName, argumentValue);
}

var env = Argument("env", "DEV");

//… many tasks 

ArgumentIfTask("Run-Integration-Tests", ref env, "env", "UAT");
Task("Run-Integration-Tests")
    .IsDependentOn("Build")
    .Does(() =>
        {
            NUnit("./src/**/bin/release/*.Tests.dll");
        });
```